# How to map quantiles values of a column to a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to append the values of a column to the data frame in Python. So for each value of column Number of House I would like to append a column that maps the quantile value of it. Wonder if anyone could advise?

See picture attached.
[sample image of end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXS0L.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **rounding** from **quantile**, suppose your data frame is `df`
you can trye:

```
df['Number of House - Quantiles Value'] = list(map(round, df['Number of House']))
```

Or use your function for **quantile** instead of `round`.

Comment: Thank you Sadra! So I have the following dataframe: 

`df=data[['rent',house_price','number_of_houses']]`



and I calculated the quantiles of number_if_houses like this:

`df['number_of_houses_quantiles'] = (df['number_of_houses'].quantile(q=[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,0.95, 1]))`




but this it doesn’t actually maps back the value of quantiles for the corresponding range of number of houses.

Comment: I suppose `quantile` is not what you're looking for.
It just return values associated with each quantile value in your data frame (i.e example min value for `0` and  max for `1.0` and goes linear for others)